# Copying every nth line from text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a very large data set (~7 million lines) from a data logger. I would like to sample the data and copy every 800th line to a new text file. The motive for this is that the text file is too large to import into my analysis software. Ideally, I would like to use a batch script or something similar. Speed is very important, as it is possible that future data files could be even larger.

At one point, I had something kind of working using:

```
findstr/N . test.txt| findstr ^[0-9]*0: >temporaryFile
FOR /F "tokens=1,* delims=: " %%i in (temporaryfile) do echo %%j > outputFile.txt
```

Which would keep one line out of every 10. I am not super familiar with the syntax, and this does not currently work as intended.

Edit:

The solution put in by @LotPings works well

Comment: What's question? :)

Comment: I have no idea how performant this powershell one liner is on huge files `Get-Content oldfile | Where {($_.ReadCount % 800) -eq 0}|Set-Content newfile`

Comment: If I am in the wrong, forum or board, my apologies. As you probably saw, I am new to this group. I typically code in MATLAB since I typically code for engineering applications. In this particular instance MATLAB is too slow because of the size of the files. I did quite a bit of research and most of the solutions were written for linux shell commands, which won't work on our windows lab computers. Of course, I don't value my time more than anyone else's, but I was hoping that maybe someone had tried this before. Again if I am in the wrong board, let me know.

Comment: Here is a good article on the optimizing the performance of Powershell when using large files. https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/06/17/optimizing-performance-of-get-content-for-large-files/

Comment: Today you can run linux `bash` even in windows !!! So try the linux `split` command in `windows` `bash` !

Comment: The example code you have given reads the file and adds line numbers (`findstr /n`), then discards those lines which begin with a line number ending in zero (the second `findstr`), writes a temporary file, reads the temporary file and discards the line number (`for /f`) and writes the target file line by line. Just about *any* other way of solving the problem would be *massively* more efficient.

Comment: Another good article about reading with PowerShell. An optimized `Get-Content -ReadCount` can do almost as well as `[System.IO.File]`. http://www.happysysadm.com/2014/10/reading-large-text-files-with-powershell.html